# Algebraic dependency over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields, computer-algebra

Let $f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}$ be $n$ polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{2}[x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}]$
such that $\forall a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$ we have $\forall i\in[n]:f_{i}(a)=a_{i}$.

> Can $f_{i}$'s be algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?.

Or even, can we say something about lower bound on the transcendence
degree of this set $\{f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}\}$ of polynomials
over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Comment: What does the restriction $f_i(a)=a_i$ mean? What are $a_i$?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev $a\in\mathbb F_2^n$ is a tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You have $n$ $f_i$ and $2^n$ $a$. Do you take only the first $n$ $a$'s?

Comment: @joro I think he means that for all $n$ many $f_i$'s and $2^n$ many $a$'s, $f_i(a)=a_i$.

Comment: So an example would be $f_i(x) = x_i$, right?

Comment: @VítTuček, Yes.

Comment: @Turbo The question is whether there is another polynomial $0 \neq g \in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that $g(f_1, \ldots, f_n)=0$.

Comment: @Peter such polynomial is $x(x+1)$, though it is actually zero.

Comment: @joro The question is whether the resulting polynomial is zero itself, not whether it represents the constant function with value zero.

Comment: @PeterArndt Another example $x_1^2x_2^3 + x_1^3 x_2^3$. Observe that for n>0 $x^n=x$.

Comment: @joro See my last comment: These are non-zero polynomials, which happen to represent the zero function. But the question of algebraic dependence is whether one can produce the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 23):

Not for $n=2$. I'm afraid this answer uses a lot more algebraic geometry than the question; I spent some time trying to remove it and failed.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f_1$ and $f_2$ obey a polynomial relation $g(x,y)$. Let $X$ be the curve $g(x,y) = 0$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}^2$ (the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$) and let $\tilde{X}$ be its normalization. So $(f_1, f_2)$ gives a map $\mathbb{A}^2 \to X$ which, since $\mathbb{A}^2$ is normal, must factor through $\tilde{X}$.

This describes $\tilde{X}$ as the image of a rational variety, so $\tilde{X}$ is unirational. For curves, unirational is the same as rational. So $X$ is a genus zero curve (with some number of punctures.) But a genus zero curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_2$ can have at most three $\mathbb{F}_2$-points, so the map $\mathbb{A}^2 \to \tilde{X}$ must identify two of the four $\mathbb{F}_2$-points of $\mathbb{A}^2$. This contradicts that these points are supposed to have distinct images under the composition $\mathbb{A}^2 \to \tilde{X} \to X \subset \mathbb{A}^2$.

I see no reason the result should hold for $n=3$, and have played a little with a counterexample where $\mathbb{A}^3$ maps to a cubic surface, but I haven't found an example yet. For example, $x^2 y + x y^2 + z^2 + z$ is a smooth cubic that passes through all eight points of $(\mathbb{F}_2)^3$ (and even remains a smooth cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ through all fifteen points of $\mathbb{P^2}(\mathbb{F}_2)$); I see no reason that we couldn't map $\mathbb{A}^3$ to it.

---

Observation: The key question is whether there is a polynomial map $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^N$, for any $N$, which is defined over $\mathbb{F}_2$, has $(n-1)$-dimensional image and is injective on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. If so, we can easily interpolate $n$ polynomials in $N$ variables so that the composite $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^N \to \mathbb{A}^n$ is the identity on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Comment: This proof can be elementarized quite a bit: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are algebraically dependent, then $\mathbb F_2(f_1,f_2)\subseteq\mathbb F_2(x_1,x_2)$ has transcendence degree $1$ over $\mathbb F_2$. By Theorem 4, Chapter 1 in Schinzel's book `Polynomials with special regard to reducibility', there is a polynomial $g\in\mathbb F_2[x_1,x_2]$ with $\mathbb F_2(f_1,f_2)=\mathbb F_2(g)$. So $f_i=h_i(g(x_1,x_2))$ for univariate polynomials $h_i$. In particular, the pairs $(f_1(a),f_2(a))$ assume at most $2$ different values, while the assumption requires $4$ values.

Comment: ... continued: The proof of the background result in Schinzel is quite elementary, like the direct field theoretic proofs of Lüroth's Theorem.

Comment: @PeterMueller I think the $h_i$ should be rational functions, not polynomials. So $(f_1(a), f_2(a))$ can assume three values, not two. But that is good enough, and otherwise I agree. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Neat answer!  Are there "Castelonuovo theorem" (unirational => rational) results on surfaces with rational points over finite fields that would work for n=3?  Your answer seems to suggest that you don't think so...

Comment: @DavidLampert I think Zariski surfaces http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_surface should give a counter-example to unirational --> rational in this setting. But the bigger problem is that rational surfaces are just much wilder than rational curves. For example, $X^2 Y + X Y^2 + W^2 Z + W Z^2 =0$ is a smooth cubic surface over $\mathbb{F}^2$ with $15$ $\mathbb{F}_2$ points.

Comment: I forgot to add the keyword in my previous comment: "smooth RATIONAL cubic surface". (It contains a pair of skew lines defined over $\mathbb{F}_2$, namely $X=W=0$ and $Y=Z=0$.)

Comment: @PeterMueller if $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are algebraically dependent, can we say that there are _polynomials_ $g_1,\dots,g_{n-1} \in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ where $\mathbb{F}_2(f_1,\dots,f_n)=\mathbb{F}_2(g_1,\dots,g_{n-1})$ ? If this is the case, then we can generalized the arguement to any $n$ right ?

Comment: @PeterMueller, Let's try to extend your proof for larger $n$. Assume that if $\mathbb{F}_{2}[f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n}]$
has transcendence degree $k<n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ then $\mathbb{F}_{2}(f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n})=\mathbb{F}_{2}(g_{1},g_{2},\ldots,g_{k})$
for $g_{i}\in\mathbb{F}_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$, is the only
issue is that how to make sure that these $g_{i}$ can be chosen from
$\mathbb{F}_{2}[x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}]$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$?
In particular, we just need that all $g_{i}'s$ are defined on all
of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$?

Comment: @eig There are two flaws with this argument. The first is that unirational (what you can deduce from being a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_2(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$) is weaker than rational (isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2(g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1})$) once $n>2$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_surface .

Comment: The second is that, if $f_i = h_i(g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1})$ for $h_i$ a rational function and $g_j$ some rational functions, then $f_i(a)$ need not be determined by $(g_1(a), \ldots, g_{n-1}(a))$. Now that I think about it, I'm a little confused about how to write PeterMueller's argument to address this in the $n=2$ case as well. I think about it in terms of abstract algebraic curves, but I run into the same problem once I get to surfaces.

Comment: @GoravJindal Besides needing the $g_i$ to be polynomials, don't you need the $h_j$ to be polynomials, where $f_j = h_j(g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1})$?

Comment: @PeterMueller, I think it is okay even if we have $f_{i}=\frac{h_{i}(g)}{k_{i}(g)}$.
I can assume $k_{i}(g)$ to be non zero since $f_{i}$ is defined
on all of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2}$, then his argument of at most 2 different
values still works.

Comment: @GoravJindal Good point! I also checked the Schinzel reference, it does give that $g$ is a polynonial (in the $n=2$ case) but it doesn't say in an obvious place that the $h_j$ are polynomials. So, I agree, if unirational implied rational and if we knew the $g_j$ were polynomials, we'd be done. I'm still skeptical, though.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, even something weaker would suffice. If $g_i$'s are well defined on all of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$ then also we should be done.

Comment: @David: If $h(g(x))$ is a polynomial, where $g$ is a polynomial and $h$ is a rational function, then $h$ is actually a polynomial. (Write $h(z)=p(z)/q(z)$, then $1=u(z)p(z)+v(z)q(z)$ by Bezout, so $1=u(g(x))p(g(x))+v(g(x))q(g(x))$, thus the numerator and denominator of $p(g(x))/q(g(x))$ are relatively prime, so $q$ is a constant.)

Comment: @PeterMueller Thanks! Okay, now we need to deal with $n>2$.